# Проверка теста (10 предложений)

Tags: тесты

1. Предложения с прямой речью состоят из слов автора и прямой речи, которые объединяются между собой бессоюзной связью. (да)
2. Прямая речь не может быть передана в виде диалога. (нет)
3. Косвенная речь — это дословно воспроизведённая чужая речь, которая на письме заключается в кавычки. (нет)
4. Цитата — это дословная выдержка (отрывок) из какого-либо текста с указанием автора или источника. (да)
5. Эпиграф — это цитата, изречение, помещаемые автором перед своим произведением (или перед отдельной частью) и характеризующие его основную идею. (да)
6. Прямая речь может состоять из одного, двух и более предложений. (да)
7. Прямая речь используется только в научном и официально-деловом стилях. (нет)
8. Предложение с косвенной речью представляет собой простое осложнённое предложение. (да)
9. Если цитата приводится не полностью, то на месте пропуска ставится многоточие. (да)
10. Основная сфера использования цитации — устная разговорная речь. (нет)

Проверьте, пожалуйста, мои ответы (только да/нет).